# How to pass an activerecord connection to a custom gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I am trying to pass an an activerecord connection to a gem that updates my database and several tables. I have been unsuccessful so far. I need multiple threads that all connect to the DB to add data.

Main code that calls the MyGem gem

```
database_yml = File.expand_path('database.yml', File.dirname(__FILE__))
db_config = YAML.load_file(database_yml)
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_config)

puts "Command array: #{options_array}"
threads = options_array.length
options_array.pmap(threads) do |option|
  MyGem::RoboCopy.run_and_parse_robocopy option, connection
end
```

The Gem Method this calls

```
module MyGem
  class RoboCopy
    def self.run_and_parse_robocopy(options, db_connection)
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection db_connection
      statistic = RobocopyData.create output_file: options[:output_file], file_gen_start: Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), status: 'Started'
      #More Code
    end
  end
end
```

This causes the following error:

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments calling `connection` (1 for 0)

I tried

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection = db_connection
```

but got this error:

NoMethodError: undefined method `connection=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the connection object itself, pass the db_config and then establish a new connection in your gem:

In your main code:

```
MyGem::RoboCopy.run_and_parse_robocopy option, db_config
```

In your gem:

```
module MyGem
  class RoboCopy
    def self.run_and_parse_robocopy(options, db_config)
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection db_config
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```